Inverse function theorem in simple ODE
I am reading an introductory book in ODEs (https://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/diffyqs.pdf, page 23) and I am struggling to understand the following:
The book states that we can solve first order ODEs in the form  $y^{′} = f(y)$ by the application of inverse function theorem:
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{f(y)} \tag{1}
$$
Then we integrate both side of the equation with respect to $y$:
$$
x(y) = \int{\frac{1}{f(y)}dy + C} \tag{2}
$$
Lastly we can try to solve for $y$.
My question is why we can put $y$ in the denominator of equation $(1)$? If I assume that $x(y)$ is the inverse of $y$ then apply the inverse function theorem to $y^{′} = f(y)$, I get something like this:
$$
\frac{dx(y)}{dy} = \frac{1}{f(x(y))} \tag{1}
$$
How $ f(x(y)) $ becomes simply $f(y)$ in $(1)$?

Write $y=g(x)$, so $x=g^{-1}(y)$. The original ODE is $g’(x)=f(g(x))$. You are considering $\color{red}{(\text{inverse function theorem in red)}}$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\color{red}{(g^{-1})’(y)=\frac1{g’(g^{-1}(y))}}=\frac1{f(g(g^{-1}(y)))}=\frac1{f(y)}.$$

Thanks, this helped a lot. Now I got where I made a mistake.
